# meaning of the phrase "see a ring on something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/valley-girl-brain/201109/6-warning-signs-hes-just-not-you%3Famp).

> If this is you, find someone to bring you back to reality. The truth is, he doesn't want a relationship—it's the same as not being ready for one—even with someone as delightful and wonderful as you. And you shouldn't waste your time trying to convince him otherwise, because his mind is already set. Bake cookies for someone who cares, like that friend who helps guide you back into reality (but not the one who assures you that he'll come around eventually).
>
> I've been in this situation before, waiting it out. Needless to say, I
>   have yet to **see a ring on it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Single Ladies by Beyoncé](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Ladies_(Put_a_Ring_on_It)) also.

“It” stands in for “me” or “my finger”. When you “put a ring on it”, you propose marriage to someone. This is because traditionally (in the US, probably in many other places too) if a person wants to marry their significant other, they will offer an engagement ring to that person. The author of the article is saying she has never been proposed to.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "see a ring on something" is not an idiom.

Your extract belongs to the second point in that article:

> 2. He tells you he's not ready for a relationship

That's the situation mentioned. In the last sentence that you quoted, the author is stating that she's been at that point, his partner saying that he's not ready for a relationship. She has been waiting for him to change, to be ready for a relationship and, futher more, to propose her (with **an engament ring**). And she have yet to **see that ring** meaning that she was never proposed by that guy.